# JavaScript Battleship Array splice

Tags: javascript, arrays, splice

I'm making a battleship game in JavaScript and I stumbled upon a problem

```
    var targetString = target.replace(/\s+/g, '');
    for(var i = 0; i !== inputArray.length; i++) {
        for(var j = 0; j !== boats[i].usedPositions.length; j++) {
            if(targetString === boats[i].usedPositions[j].toString()) {
                hit = true;
                boats[i].hits[j] = 1;
                console.log(boats[i].hits);
                currentBoat = boats[i];
                boats[i].usedPositions.splice(j,1);
                break;
            }                                
        }  
    }
```

---

```
    if(hit && stop == false) {
        alert ("Hit!");
        if(allEquals(currentBoat.hits, 1) && hit) {
            alert("Boat with length " + currentBoat.hits.length + " has sunken!");
            sunkenBoat++;
        }
    }
```

The first piece of code checks if the entered coordinate matches a coordinate of the boats (all of these are stored in usedPositions). To prevent that the player can hit that boat again, I want to take the hit coordiante out of that array using splice. But when I do this, it doesn't alert me when a boat has sunken (second piece of code). When the line with splice in is removed, it does give the alert. Can anyone help me? Full code is found [here](http://pastebin.com/PwCLm8gA).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`splice` moves the subsequent array elements down to fill the space. Your logic doesn't look like it's expecting things to move like that.

Instead of `splice`, you probably just want to assign some other value to that array location, e.g.:

```
boats[i].usedPositions[j] = " "; // Where " " is assumed not to represent a boat
```